# how to disable fullscreen playing with html5 video tag in iphone?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, video, web

I use a video tag in my page.

I hope it played without fullscreen.

but Safari with iPhone forces it to start playing with fullscreen.

How can I avoid fullscreen playing?

i have tried .webkitCancelFullScreen() and .webkitDisplayingFullscreen.

it seems not work well.

Comment: Have you tried to apply css properties `max-height/width` to the video element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. Take a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1) it cleary states that "Safari optimizes video presentation for the smaller screen on iPhone or iPod touch by playing video using the full screen".

Tough luck I guess :(

Comment: yes,i have read that document too. but it has the opportunity to bypass this setting or not